# JDBC THIN Oracle with Java6

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

I have a problem with JDBC Thin in Oracle 11g with NetBeans V6.7.1. I don't know how to configure it. I have already set classpath of ojdbc6.jar and orai18n.jar. But I still can't run this example in NetBeans:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
class JDBCVersion
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException
    {
        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:easycash/oracle@oracle:1521/validus");
        Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
        // Create Oracle DatabaseMetaData object
        DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
        // gets driver info:
        System.out.println("JDBC driver version is " + meta.getDriverVersion());
    }
}
```

Could anyone help finish my work?

Thanks,
Sopolin

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to run this?

Answer (score 1):

If the error is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dms.console.DMSConsole
```

You will need the **dms.jar** that comes with the Oracle Database.

In my case this jar is located inside lib folder of OC4J.

This only happen when you use ojdbc*dms.jar. From the JDBC download site:

"Same as ojdbc6.jar, **except that it contains instrumentation to support DMS and limited java.util.logging calls**."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class JDBCVersion
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException
    {
        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:validus");
        ods.setUser("easycash");
        ods.setPassword("oracle");
        Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
        // Create Oracle DatabaseMetaData object
        DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
        // gets driver info:
        System.out.println("JDBC driver version is " + meta.getDriverVersion());
    }
}
```

Did you have the oracle-dms.jar in your Classpath?

Comment: I don't have. Could you tell why?

Comment: my Oracle-Driver was complaining about missing DMS-classe